# How can I implement input validation for the PrimeVue InputNumber component using vee-validate?

Tags: typescript, validation, vuejs3, vee-validate, primevue

Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "modelValue". Expected String with value "[object Object]", got Object

the modelValue must be a strinf but the InputNumber emit field (an object )

here is a part of my code :

```
<Field
          v-model="internalValue"
          :name="options.label"
          :rules="computedRules"
          v-slot="{ field, errorMessage }"
        >
          <InputNumber
            v-bind="field"
            :label="options.label"
            @input="$emit('update:modelValue', internalValue)"
          >
          </InputNumber>
          <small class="p-error" id="text-error" v-if="errorMessage">{{ errorMessage || '&nbsp;' }}</small>
</Field>

-------------------
props: {
      label: String,
      modelValue: {
        type: String,
        default: '0',
      },
}
setup(props , { emit }) {
      const internalValue = computed(
        {
          get() : number{
            return props.modelValue!='' ? parseInt(props.modelValue) : 0;
          },
          set(value : number) {
            emit("update:modelValue", value);
          },
        },
      );
  return{
     internalValue
  }
}
```

the difference between InputNumber and InputText is that field in InputNumber got "
{
"name": "Number",
"value": {"originalEvent":"[object KeyboardEvent]","value":1,"formattedValue":0}} "
but in InputText got "
{
"name": "Text",
"value": "test"
}
"